# JavaScript Login form document.getElementById is not detecting value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, login-script

Can anybody tell me why document.getElementById is not detecting the entered password in the code below:

```js
function myFunction() {

  let email = "name@email.com";
  let password = "password";

  if (document.getElementById("password") == password) {
    Console.console.log("success");
  } else {
    console.log("Failure");
    console.log(password);
    console.log(document.getElementById("password"));
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form action="#">
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="text">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to log it's value in the console I just get input id="password" type="text"and I am not sure what this means other than for some reason it is not having the value I want assigned to it.

-Thanks

Comment: You've to use `document.getElementById("password").value` Notice the **value** part.

Comment: You are not calling the `.value` property of the DOM element

Comment: In addition to the answer given by @asprin, remember to always use `===` (three equals) when comparing values in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `document.getElementById` returns a DOM Element Object. This object has various attributes like `.style`, but to get the text entered for an `<input>` element, you want the `.value` attribute.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let email = "name@email.com";
    let password = "password";

    if (document.getElementById("password").value == password){
        console.log("success");
    } else {
        console.log("Failure");
        console.log(password);
        console.log(document.getElementById("password").value);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="text">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
   if(document.getElementById("password") == password){
   console.log(document.getElementById("password"));
```

to these lines

```
   if(document.getElementById("password").value == password){
   console.log(document.getElementById("password").value);
```

and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

your implementation is ok, but you did a slight mistake. document returns an object with multiple keys. Among those keys 'value' key contains the value of your input field.

```
document.getElementById("password").value
```

will return your desired value.

Note: You can access all the attributes from this object. For example

```
document.getElementById("password").placeholder
```

will return the hint from the input field